# Transaction check error during CUDA installation on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA on a Linux CentOS 7 x86_64 AWS instance via the [installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) and running into an error that I cannot resolve.

Here are the steps I took:

I verified that I had `gcc` and a CUDA-compatible NVIDIA GPU

I installed the kernel headers: `sudo yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r) kernel-headers-$(uname -r)`

I grabbed the CUDA repo: `wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/rhel7/x86_64/cuda-repo-rhel7-10.1.105-1.x86_64.rpm`

and installed it:

```
sudo rpm -i cuda-repo-rhel7-10.1.105-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install cuda
```

It downloaded the file but then I got the following error at the end:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 from install of libglvnd-glx-1:1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mesa-libGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libEGL.so.1 from install of libglvnd-egl-1:1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mesa-libEGL-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.x86_64
```

Just to see if it would still work, I updated the path: `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/NsightCompute-2019.1${PATH:+:${PATH}}`

And then tested it: `nvcc --version`

But it couldn't find CUDA. What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the latest packages in a CentOS 7.  You should be able to do this by running “yum update”

This was fixed in https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:3059